# Prove $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I need to prove the following statement:

$$(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) = A$$

I did the following steps:

\begin{align}
&(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) = A \\
&A \cup B \cap (A \cup A) = A \\
&A \cup B \cap A = A \quad \text{via absorption law} \\
&A = A
\end{align}

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all your way of writing is not acceptable in general... I do not really understand your intention in what you have written after "I did the following steps:"

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I wrote the proof after "I did the following steps:". While it not be written very formally, I believe it captures the gist of the argument. If you still do not understand what I mean, please specify and I will be more than happy clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some feedback.  Most importantly, I have no idea how you got from the first line to the second line.

Also, please try to avoid writing $\;X \cup Y \cap Z\;$: always write parentheses in such a case, even if common convention would allow skipping a few.  Economy of symbols becomes harmful when there is potential confusion.  And more importantly, $\;\cup\;$ and $\;\cap\;$ are perfect duals, so any precedence convention destroys symmetry.

Now, I would write down the proof [Semsem](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/117040/semsem)'s answer in a different format.  That format helps to make clear the intention of what you are doing.

We're trying to simplify $\;(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c)\;$ to $\;A\;$.  Therefore, we calculate
\begin{align}
& (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) \\
= & \qquad \text{"simplify: distributive law in reverse -- bringing the $\;B\;$'s together"} \\
& A \cup (B \cap B^c) \\
= & \qquad \text{"simplify: set and complement have nothing in common"} \\
& A \cup \emptyset \\
= & \qquad \text{"simplify: adding empty set is a no-op"} \\
& A \\
\end{align}
This proves the original statement.

An advantage of this format (see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) under "The proof format") is there is explicit room to explain each of the steps.  As Dijkstra says, "it is absolutely essential that at least one line is available for each hint, so as to discourage economizing on them."

Answer (score 5):

No. Using distribution law$$(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup B^c) = A \cup( B \cap  B^c) = A \cup\emptyset=A$$

Comment: I'm slightly confused with the distribution law. It says $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$. In this case, what's $C$?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I can't follow how you got from the first step to the second step without some justification, but here is one approach:

\begin{align}
(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup B^c) & \text{Given} \\
((A\cup B)\cap A)\cup ((A\cup B)\cap B^c) & \text{Using Distributive Law} \\
((A\cap A)\cup (A\cap B)) \cup ((A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap B^c)) & \text{Using Distributivity Again} \\
(A\cup (A\cap B)) \cup(A\cap B^c) & \text{Using $A\cup A=A$, $B\cap B^c=\emptyset$, and $\emptyset \cup C=C$} \\
A \cup (A\cap B^c) & \text{Using Absorption Law} \\
A & \text{Using Absorption Law one last time}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Your second step is invalid. $A \cup B^c \neq A \cup A$
A better option may be to distribute the intersection over the union as follow
$((A \cup B) \cap A) \cup ((A \cup B) \cap B^c)$ and work from there